# Prove that the additive groups $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ are not isomorphic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Is there a better (or other) way(s) to prove the following statement? Also, the same argument works for multiplicative groups $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{Q}-\{0\}$, right?

---

> **Problem** Prove that the additive groups $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ are not isomorphic.

**Solution** By cantor's diagonal argument, there is no possible bijection between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$. Since an isomorphism needs to be a bijection, there is no possible isomorphism between the additive groups $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$.

---

Thanks

Comment: Does Isomorphism preserve countability??

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik It must preserve cardinality, as it must be a bijection.

Comment: This certainly works, and I know of no better way.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Oh, sorry. I suppose OP already knows this as it was listed as their reasoning in their post. I believe the question is asking not if the proof is correct, but if there is some other way to prove this.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I do not understand your question. Isomorphism has to be a bijection. Hence, if two groups are isomorphic, then they must have the same cardinality. I know this. I am wondering if there are other ways to prove this fact.

Answer (score 16):

Let $\Phi: \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ homomorphism of additive groups. Then $\Phi$ is already determined by $\Phi(1)$ (as  $\Phi(\frac{a}{b})= \Phi(\frac{1}{b})+ ... + \Phi(\frac{1}{b})$ ($a$ summands) and $\Phi(1)= \Phi(\frac{1}{b}) + ... + \Phi(\frac{1}{b}) $, ($b$ summands))

Now, say $\sqrt{2} \cdot \Phi(1)$ doesn't have a preimage.

Edit: I just saw this was remarked by @Robert M in a comment to his answer.

Comment: This answer is very nice. I used your idea to prove this (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620551/prove-that-the-additive-groups-mathbbz-and-mathbbq-are-not-isomorphic).

Comment: You can simplify at the other question by using that for a homomorphism $\Phi: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$, say $\frac{1}{2} \Phi(1)$ will not have a preimage.

Answer (score 7):

This is another approach: If $(\Bbb{R},+) \cong (\Bbb{Q},+)$ then $\Bbb{R} \cong \Bbb{Q}$ as vector spaces over $\Bbb{Q}$ which is impossible since one is one dimensional and the other is infinite dimensional.

Comment: Why must the map be a vector space isomorphism? It need not fix $ \Bbb Q$.

Comment: In fact there are non-isomorphic vector spaces that are isomorphic not only as groups but as fields (the algebraic closure of $\Bbb C(x)$ and $\Bbb C$).

Comment: @PVAL  If $f(a + b) = f(a) + f(b)$ then $f(mz) = mf(z)$. Let $z = \frac xm$ then we drive $f(\frac xm) = \frac {1}{m}f(x)$. Now let $x = nt$ and we get $f(\frac{n}{m}t)  = \frac {1}{m}f(nt) = \frac{n}{m}f(t)$. Satisfied ?

Comment: @PVAL: any abelian group has at most one structure of a $\mathbf Q$-vector space. If two abelian groups admit the structure of a $\mathbf Q$-vector space, then homomorphisms between them are automatically $\mathbf Q$-linear. So if two torsion-free injective abelian groups are isomorphic as abelian groups, they are isomorphic as $\mathbf Q$-vector spaces.

Comment: It would be helpful to explain the reason when you downvote a correct answer !

Answer (score 2):

The quotient of $\mathbb{Q}$ by a cyclic subgroup (namely $\mathbb{Z}$) is torsion. $\mathbb{R}$ has no such subgroup.

Comment: The last comment above may be tough without proof for someone asking this question...

Comment: I have not yet covered quotient groups. It is only in chapter $3$ of Dummit and Foote. I am still in chapter $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $F : Q → R$ be isomorphism of additive groups.

$n^\frac{1}{2}$ belongs to $\Bbb R$ for all $n$ natural number

Since $F$ is isomorphism, there exist unique $\frac{p}{q}$ in $Q$ for unique $n$ such that $F(\frac{p}{q}) =  n^\frac{1}{2}$

$$
F\left(\frac{p}{q}\right) = F\left(\frac{1}{q} + \frac{1}{q} + \ldots + \frac{1}{q}\right) =  p\cdot F\left(\frac{1}{q}\right) = n^\frac{1}{2}\qquad\qquad\mathbf{(1)}
$$

$$F(1) = F\left(\frac{q}{q}\right) = q \cdot F\left(\frac{1}{q}\right) = q \cdot \frac{n^\frac{1}{2}}{p}\qquad\qquad\mathbf{(2)}$$

Hence,

$$F(1) = \frac{q_1 \cdot (1)^\frac{1}{2}}{p_1} = \frac{q_2 \cdot (2)^\frac{1}{2}}{p_2} = \frac{q_3 \cdot (3)^\frac{1}{2}}{p_3} =\ldots$$

So, $\frac{q_1 \cdot p_2}{p_1 \cdot q_2} = (2)^\frac{1}{2}$ where LHS is rational and RHS irrational

This imply our assumption is incorrect. Therefore, there doesn't exist an isomorphism $F$.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Have a look at [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to improve the look of your equations