# How to prove isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra

(Q*,•) and (R*,•) is isomorphic.

This is false.

Why this problem false??

Would you ask to me counter-example?

Comment: Forget the operation, they do not even have the same number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

From your notation I guess that $\mathbb{Q}^*$ are the invertible elements in $\mathbb{Q}$ and you want to show that $\mathbb{Q}^*$ and $\mathbb{R}^*$ are not isomorphic as groups? Well, in that case, notice that $\mathbb{Q}^*=\mathbb{Q}_0$ and $\mathbb{R}^*=\mathbb{R}_0$, the first set is countable whereas the second is not. Therefore they cannot be isomorphic as that would yield that they are bijective.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to prove this. An isomorphism is a function $\Phi$ that is a bijective homomorphism. By Cantor's diagonal argument, there is no bijection from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$.

Also quoting @Louis in his answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620514/prove-that-the-additive-groups-mathbbr-and-mathbbq-are-not-isomorphic/%22here%22), that can also be applied to the multiplicative groups $\mathbb{R}^*$ and $\mathbb{Q}^*$

> Let $\Phi: \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ homomorphism of additive
>   groups. Then $\Phi$ is already determined by $\Phi(1)$ (as 
>   $\Phi(\frac{a}{b})= \Phi(\frac{1}{b})+ ... + \Phi(\frac{1}{b})$ ($a$
>   summands) and $\Phi(1)= \Phi(\frac{1}{b}) + ... + \Phi(\frac{1}{b}) $,
>   ($b$ summands))
>
> Now, say $\sqrt{2} \cdot \Phi(1)$ doesn't have a preimage.