# Find all endomorphisms between (Q,+) and (R,+).Which of them are automorphisms?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism

Can you help me how can i find all endomorphisms between (Q,+) and (Q,+).Which of them are automorphisms?

Comment: There is no isomorphism between the two groups, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620514/prove-that-the-additive-groups-mathbbr-and-mathbbq-are-not-isomorphic).

Comment: "endo" should be "homo," "auto" should be "iso."